# Lost a row after saving excel as txt (check with wc -l)

Tags: excel, linux, text, type-conversion

I have an excel file with 3 rows which I saved as txt. In the terminal, I checked the number of row of the saved txt using `wc -l`, and it showed 2. I opened the txt file and I can see it is still three rows...Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `wc -l` probably is counting `\n` characters (new line characters) and a file that has three lines but does not end its last line with a new line has only two new lines at all... This is common with tools (like Excel) on exporting as text files... probably if you open the file with an editor, it will notice you that the file does not end in a new line char (or that it lacks a newline on the last line) and when you close it, the editor adds it to the file.

The convention forces to end text lines with an end of line terminator (be it an ASCII CR, an ASCII LF, or a pair ASCII CR ASCII LF, depending on the operating system) but as a convention, can be followed or not.  Microsoft has always famous for driving on the left side (please pardon me, english men) and trying to establish their own conventions, so you can thing that a N lines text file can have N or N-1 line terminator chars.